# Direct deposit downside

Tags: united-states, banking, employment, paycheck

After working at a job for four years as a salaried employee, my employer has offered direct deposit. He says he has to hold a weeks pay in arrears to give time to adjust deposits for those who leave the job. Is this allowed in Alabama?

Comment: I've never held a W-2 type job where I wasn't paid in arrears.

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't find an exact law addressing this but I would assume it is allowed based on my employment in other states in the US.

Furthermore, it is definitively allowed for government employees, based off of this [document](http://www.comptroller.alabama.gov/pdfs/FAQs.pdf) from the Alabama comptroller which states

> Q: Is this something new – being paid
>   in arrears? I’ve never heard of this.
>
> A: No, it is not new. Employees are paid now
>   on a biweekly, in arrears basis. The only
>   timing change is to go to semi-monthly pay per
>   iods and checks since most employees have
>   been paid in arrears for years. We are trying to be careful to distinguish semi-monthly
>   arrears rather than just saying semi-monthly
>   pay because there are some employees who
>   are paid on a semi-monthly current basis now and will continue to be paid in this manner.